# Indexing a MongoDB on Heroku, with Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, indexing, mongoid

I have a Rails app running Mongoid on Heroku and I need to set up some indexes to make the database faster. I've tried to read about it several places and I know Mongoid has some built-in functions for indexing, but I'm not sure on what to apply them and how often to index.

It is mostly my Design-model I want to index:

```
scope :full_member_and_show, where(full_member: true).and(show: true).desc(:created_at)
scope :not_full_member_and_show, where(full_member: false).and(show: true).desc(:created_at)

embeds_many :comments
belongs_to :designer

search_in :tags_array

attr_accessible :image,  :tags, :description, :title, :featured, :project_number, :show



field :width
field :height
field :description
field :title
field :tags, type: Array
field :featured, :type => Boolean, :default => false
field :project_number, :type => Integer, :default => 0
field :show, :type => Boolean, :default => true
field :full_member, :type => Boolean, :default => false
field :first_design, :type => Boolean, :default => false
```

What do I need to index, how exactly do I do it with Mongoid and how often should I do it?

ERROR UPDATE

If try to index the below:

```
index({ full_member: 1, show: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

It throws me this error:

```
Invalid index specification {:full_member=>1, :show=>1}; should be either a string, symbol, or an array of arrays.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to index periodically: once you've added an index, mongo keeps that index up to date as the collection changes. This is the same as an index in MySQL or Postgres (you may have been thinking of something like solr)

What to index depends on what queries you'll be making against your dataset. Indexes do carry some overhead when you do updates and consume disk space so you don't want to add them when you don't need them.

You tell mongoid what indexes you want by index, for example

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  index :city
end
```

There are loads of examples in the mongoid docs for the various kinds of indexes mongo supports.

Then you run

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

This determines what indexes you want (based in the calls to `index` in your model) and then ensures that they exist in the db, creating them if necessary. In development you'd run this after adding indexes to your models. In production it makes sense to run this as part of your deploy (you only need to if you've added indexes since the last deploy but it's way easier to just do it systematically)

There's a lot of information about how mongo uses indexes in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes)

Comment: Such a nice answer. Just what I was looking for. Thanks! I'm doing it to make my database faster, so should I just make an index out of every field that I query for? Would that be the best thing to do?

Comment: Mongo only ever uses a single index to execute a single query so if you have a query that references 3 fields it won't use 3 individual indexes. It may be able to use a compound index however. There are also certain types of query (e.g. regex queries) that can't use indexes. The mongo docs have a bunch of information on how mongo uses indexes

Comment: Ok. Would it be best to index the first thing we query for then? In this case - where(full_member: true)?

Comment: In that case you'd be better off with a compound index on [:full_member,:show,:created_at] since your scopes use those three.

Comment: Very cool. I'll accept your answer now. Where can I read more about compound indexes in mongoid?

Comment: It seems like I can't index booleans... can that be true?

Comment: That doesn't sound right, although i don't think i've ever tried

Comment: Hmm.. seems a bit strange. Would really like to index the database, to speed it up. Updated the question above with the error it throws.

Comment: Looks like you're following the examples for mongoid 3, but are using mongoid 2.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm using the standard gem from github though. Why isn't the standard gem the newest version?

Comment: 3.0 is only at the release candidate stage, so rubygems gets you 2.x

Comment: Ok, cool. I managed to create indexed. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll be looking forward to mongoid 3 going public.